# Responding with js in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

We have a link_to sending an ajax post, and are wondering if there's a way to change the content of the sending  tag.

We basically want to update the database, then change the icon in the link_to block.

```
 <%= link_to add_favorite_path({type: type, id: id}), 
      type:"button", disable_with: '...', :method => :post, 
      :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm', id: "#{type}-#{id}" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<% end %>
```

Here's the favorites contoller:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :js

    def add
        @type = params[:type]
        @id     = params[:id]
        @selector = "#{@type}-#{@id}"    
    end
end
```

EDIT: add.js.erb:

```
var link = $("a#<%= @selector %>");
link.html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
```

**Found Solution:**
Could not alter the item html when using the `disable_with:` option.  Removed it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make sure the appropriate controller reponds to JS

```
respond_to :js, :html
```

Then create the view file `add.js.erb` to add the appropriate JS to render the new icon.
I would like to see more code but something like this

```
$("#id_of_link").html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i>");
```

Although, I usually create partials and escape_javascript to render the new partial in the JS

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the code, but the link won't update.  No console errors, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell me what your log says when you click the link?? (to clarify, where you start your server through your Command Line or in your log files)